# Cofinal $\Sigma_0$-embeddings between transitive models of $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$

Tags: set-theory

Let $M,N$ be transitive sets and let
$$
\pi \colon (M; \in) \to (N; \in)
$$
be $\Sigma_0$-elementary and cofinal (, i.e. $N = \bigcup \{\pi(x) \mid x \in M \}$).

Earlier today I reminded myself of the following:

> If at least one of $(M;\in), (N; \in)$ is a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$ $(\dagger)$,
>   then $\pi$ is fully elementary.

**Q.** How does one prove this fact?

---

$(\dagger)$ $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$ means $\mathrm{ZFC}$ without the powerset axiom but including the axiom scheme of collection.

Comment: I'd be happy to provide more details once I've gotten some sleep. But for now let me just say that all my attempts ended up requiring some additional assumption and that I'm not very confident that any of those approaches help with this general statement. Maybe I'm just missing the key twist -- maybe the situation is a bit more complicated than I seem to remember.

Comment: By cofinality, make every statement a bounded statement.

Comment: @Asaf Well... yes... but it's the details that got me. Anyways, I'm pretty sure I figured out the proof for the case that $(M;\in) \models \mathrm{ZFC}^-$ while attempting to fall asleep. The other case should be similar. But I'll have to check tomorrow, since I don't trust my sleep-deprived self.

Comment: Sleep deprivation is a very good way to get yourself tired. Let me know how that went.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I posted a sketch of my solution. Is this what you had in mind or is there a simpler approach that I've missed?

Answer (score 3):

As I've said in an earlier comment, I figured how to to prove this shortly after posting my question. Since I don't particularly like my solution, I've postponed answering my own question in hope someone else posted a more elegant answer first. Now that that seems unlikely, let me settle this question by providing a sketch:

The key to my proof is the proof of the Reflection Principle (as can be found in Kunen's Set Theory book for example) -- the statement alone doesn't help since $\pi[\mathrm{Ord}]$ may not contain an $N$-definable club (or any club, for that matter).

First let's suppose that $(M; \in) \models \mathrm{ZFC}^-$. Let $\vec{x} \in M$ and $\phi$ be such that $(M; \in) \models \phi[\vec{x}]$. Fix your favorite $M$-definable, monotone, cofinal sequence $(M_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in M \cap \mathrm{Ord})$ such that $\phi$ and all its subformulae are absolute between $M$ and all the $M_\alpha$ $(\dagger)$. For $\alpha \in M \cap \mathrm{Ord}$ let $N_\alpha = \pi(M_{\alpha}$). What threw me off at first is that $(N_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in M \cap \mathrm{Ord})$ typically doesn't inherent all the nice additional properties of the $M_\alpha$-sequence, but it certainly remains monotone, cofinal and, for all $\alpha$ and all $\vec{y} \in M_{\alpha}$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
(M; \in) \models \phi[\vec{y}] & \iff (M_{\alpha}; \in) \models \phi[\vec{y}] \\
& \iff (N_{\alpha}; \in) \models \phi[\pi(\vec{y})].
\end{align*}
$$
Now use this to conclude, via an induction on the complexity of $\phi$, that $(N; \in) \models \phi[\pi(\vec{x})]$.

If, on the other hand, $(N; \in) \models \mathrm{ZFC}^-$, basically the same proof works $(\ddagger)$. This time start with an $N$-definable, monotone, cofinal sequence $(N_\alpha \mid \alpha \cap N \cap \mathrm{Ord})$ of *transitive* sets such that $\phi$ and all its subformulae are absolute between all the $N_\alpha$ and $N$ and consider the pullback
$$
(\pi^{-1}[N_{\alpha}] \mid \alpha \in N \cap \mathrm{Ord}).
$$
This sequence, in my mind, looks even nastier than the one before but luckily we get that is still consists of transitive sets $(\Diamond)$ (which helps dealing with bounded formulae) that combined are cofinal in $M$ and we still get, for $\alpha \in N \cap \mathrm{Ord}$ and $\vec{y} \in \pi^{-1}[N_{\alpha}]$ that

$$
\begin{align*}
(\pi^{-1}[N_\alpha]; \in) \models \phi[\vec{y}]
& \iff (N_{\alpha}; \in) \models \phi[\vec{y}] \\
& \iff (N; \in) \models \phi[\vec{y}].
\end{align*}
$$

A similiar induction as before then finishes the proof.

---

$(\dagger)$ This exists by the Reflection Principle -- which is provable in $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$ -- and we could, if we wanted to, impose more requirements on this sequence (e.g. choose it to be continuous or to be a club-subsequece of $(V_\alpha^M \mid \alpha \in M \cap \mathrm{Ord}$).

$(\ddagger)$ We would like to have a cofinal sequence $(M_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in M \cap \mathrm{Ord})$ such that $(\pi(M_{\alpha}) \mid \alpha \in M \cap \mathrm{Ord})$ is monotone, continuous, cofinal and $N$-definable to apply the Reflection Principle and pull the statement back via $\pi$. But we can't have that -- not even if we knew that $(M; \in) \models \mathrm{ZFC}^-$.

$(\Diamond)$ To see that they are transitive, it seems easiest to look at $(\pi[M]; \in)$ as a $\Sigma_0$-substructure of $(N; \in)$ and view $\pi$ as the Mostowski collapse. Then $N_\alpha \cap \pi[M]$ collapses to the transitive set $\pi^{-1}[N_\alpha]$.

Comment: If someone has a more elegant solution to offer, I'd be very interested in seeing that. (I have a vague memory that at least for one of the two cases there is a very short proof. If one is interested in finding that: Note that we get $\Sigma_1$-elementarity for free, so you may assume $\pi$ is $\Sigma_1$-elementary to begin with.)